# Proprieties of the Fractional Laplacian on unbounded domain

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fractional-calculus

I'm interesting to the stochastic PDE

$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial t}(t,x)=\Delta_{\mathbf{\alpha }}u(t,x) + {\dot{W}}(t,x), \\u(0,x)=u_{0}(x),\,\,\,\, x\in\mathbb{R}.\end{array}\right.$$

where $\Delta_{\alpha}= -\left(-\Delta\right)^{\frac{\alpha}{2}}$ with  $0 < \alpha \leq 2$. My problem is that I dont know some properties of this operator, especially

1. Its domain ?
2. If there exists a ONB of $L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$ of eigenvectors of this operator ?
3. If there exists $\delta\in (0,1)\,$ such that $(\Delta_{\alpha})^{-1 + \delta}\,$ is a trace class operator.
4. If there exists a reference where I can find a study of this operator ? 
   Thank you for your help

Comment: I can't offer much since I only have a cursory understanding of fractional differential equations but from what I know, these kinds of problems are often solved by Fourier transform techniques. This could be useful for you since the Fourier transform converts fractional derivatives into fractional powers and somewhat turns the equation into an algebraic one.

Comment: Yes, this operator can be defined via Fourier transform, but with only the definition I can't do an important thnigs. Thank you for your interest.

Comment: As for references, try Grafakos *Classical and Modern Fourier Analysis* or Stein *Singular Integrals and Differentiability Properties of Functions*.